# Looping through last row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

My code is looping through all rows except the last one. How can I fix it??

```
Sub Send_CPR_Expiration_Sites()

Dim iCounter As Integer

Dim Dest As Variant

Dim SDest As String

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application

Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem

' Create a new Outlook object

For iCounter = 4 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


' Subject

strSubj = "Immediate Action Required: Out of Compliance for "

On Error GoTo dbg

' Create a new item (email) in Outlook

strbody = ""

SiteLead = Cells(iCounter, 41).Value

SafetyR = Cells(iCounter, 42).Value

SafetySR = Cells(iCounter, 43).Value

SafetySS = Cells(iCounter, 44).Value

SiteCode = Cells(iCounter, 6).Value

'Make the body of an email

strbody = "Dear " & SiteCode & " Team," & vbCrLf

strbody = strbody & vbCrLf

strbody = strbody & "blah blah blah" & vbCrLf

strbody = strbody & vbCrLf

strbody = strbody & "Let us know if you have any questions. Thank you!"

strbody = strbody & vbCrLf

objOutlookMsg.To = SiteLead

objOutlookMsg.CC = SafetyR & ";" & SafetySR & ";" & SafetySS

objOutlookMsg.Importance = olImportanceHigh

objOutlookMsg.Subject = strSubj & SiteCode

objOutlookMsg.BodyFormat = 1

objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add "C:\Users"

objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add "C:\Users"

' 1 – text format of an email, 2 -  HTML format

objOutlookMsg.Body = strbody

objOutlookMsg.Display

Next iCounter

dbg:

'Display errors, if any

If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing

Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For iCounter = 4 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
```

If you had blanks in (eg) A1:A2 and data in A3:A20 then the loop is going to run from 4 to 18, not 4 to 20

This is a better way to set the end of the for loop:

```
For iCounter = 4 To Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: That sounds like a different question.